# Running loop number of times as per number of lines in the content of the text file ( Unix Shell Scripting )

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I  have some multiple lines in the text file . 
Example: I have 3 lines in the text file and

```
Emp_Table_Columns.txt|Employee_Temp.csv|Emp.csv
Dep_Table_Columns.txt|Dep_Temp.csv|Dep.csv
Line_Table_Columns.txt|Line_Temp.csv|Line.csv
```

I want to run my FOR loop ( or any other loop )   for 3 times and while running i want to pass the values Field 1 , Field 2 , field 3 into a variables.

Lets say if 1st Loop is running , then  i will be reading Emp_Table_Columns.txt . If 2nd loop is running i will be reading Dep_Table_Columns.txt. Please help me with some suggestion in Shell Script or linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a for loop.  You want to iterate over all the lines in the file.  eg

```
while IFS=\| read col1 col2 col3 etc; do 
   ...
done < text_file
```

In the body of the loop, the variables `$col1`, `$col2`, and `$col3` will contain the values in column 1, column 2, and column 3, respectively. The variable `$etc` will contain columns 4 and beyond (if there is any; you probably expect `$etc` to be the empty string).  Name the variables whatever you desire, hopefully with names that are descriptive of the contents of the columns.  Note that we explicitly set `IFS` to use `|` as the column separator, as `read` will by default split on whitespace (depending on the current value of IFS.)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. Can you elaborate the answer.

Comment: Not sure how to elaborate.  There is much information on using using read in a while loop available on the internet.

Comment: One Doubt. It means if i use this while loop as per number of lines the loop will run and as per loop number respective line values i can read into variables. Am i right ?

Comment: The loop will run one iteration for each line of the file until it can not read any more lines from the file.

Comment: Note that this is not necessarily the same as "once for each line of the file", since the number of lines in the file can be very dynamic.  If the loop is appending data to the file, or if some other process truncates the file, or if there is a hardware failure that causes a read error, unexpected things may happen.  If, however, the file is not changing and there are no errors, it is not unreasonable to think of this as looping over each line of the file.